# In Elixir, how can I split a string with non-word characters are separators, but also allow for math operators like +, -, etc.?

Tags: regex, string, split, elixir, separator

In Elixir, I would like to split a string, treating all the non-word characters as separators, including the "Ogham Space Mark ( )" (which should not be confused for a minus (-) sign).

So, if I split the string:

```
"1\x002\x013\n4\r5 6\t7 + asda - 3434"
```

The result should be:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","+","asda","-","3434"]
```

I'm *trying* to figure out how to do this with Regex, but the best I've been able to accomplish so far is:

```
Regex.split(~r/[\W| ]+/, input_string)
```

.... but this drops the `+` and `-` sign as these are not considered word characters.

or

```
Regex.split(~r/[^[:punct:]|^[:alnum:]| ]+/, input_string)
```

but this fails to split on the Ogham Space Mark.

This will actually work correctly, but it is inelegant for the extra transformation:

```
Regex.split(~r/[^[:punct:]|^[:alnum:]]+/, String.replace(input_string, " ", " "))
```

Is there any way to split this with a single Regex invocation?

Comment: It seems that you need `[^\w+-]+`.

Comment: Why do you want to split the string? Are you trying to tokenise a mathematical equation? Are there a known list of operators?

Comment: @revo , the result does not split on the Ogham Space Mark and does weird things with the surrounding characters (e.g. instead of "4", "5", "6",   I get  "4", <<53, 225>>, "6"

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, I am working on a solution for  Exercism's "Forth" challenge, so yes I need to tokenize and yes there is a list of known operators I'll need to support (+, -, *, /).

Comment: Try `~r/(*UTF)(*UCP)[^\w\/*+-]+/`, with the two `(*UTF)(*UCP)` PCRE verbs at the start.

Comment: This works: ~r/[^[:alnum:]]/u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elixir regular expressions are handled by the PCRE regex engine, and your input string contains characters from the whole Unicode character table, not just the ASCII part.

You may enable Unicode mode with the help of two PCRE verbs, `(*UTF)(*UCP)`:

```
Regex.split(~r/(*UTF)(*UCP)[^\w\/*+-]+/, "1\x002\x013\n4\r5 6\t7 + asda - 3434")
```

It will output:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "+", "asda", "-", "3434"]
```

See the [Elixir demo online](https://rextester.com/PSZR30988).

**NOTE**: `~r/[^\w\/*+-]+/u` and `~r/(*UTF)(*UCP)[^\w\/*+-]+/`  are *equivalent*, `u` is a shorthand for the two PCRE verbs.

The regex matches

- `(*UTF)(*UCP)` - `(*UTF)` treats the input string as a Unicode code point sequence and `(*UCP)` makes the `\w` Unicode aware (so that is matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` characters)
- `[^\w\/*+-]+`  - 1 or more characters other than letters, digits, `/`, `*`, `+` and `-`.

Note that `-` in the meaning of a literal `-` char does not have to be escaped when placed at the end of the character class.

Comment: This works, but is there a way to match the operators /, *, + as a class (possibly containing other members) instead of individually?

Comment: @BrianKessler What kind of class do you have in mind? I understand you want to match any non-word char except for a couple other non-word chars. Just use `~r/(*UTF)(*UCP)[^\w<CHARS_TO_EXCLUDE>]+/` or `~r/[^\w<CHARS_TO_EXCLUDE>]+/u`.

Comment: ... Actually, I think what I want is [:punct:]  :-)

Comment: @BrianKessler Just FYI, `[:punct:]` includes both `\p{P}` (punctuation proper) and `\p{S}` (symbols).